# Angular: How do I grab the input value of my form in the controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have a form:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
    New Chore: <br>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Hours: <input type="text" name="hours"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and in my controller:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    if ($scope.name) {
        alert("here");
        $scope.chores.push({name: $scope.name, hours: $scope.hours});
        $scope.name = '';
    } else {
        alert("none");
    }
};
```

But it is always going to the `else` statement. How do I grab the name and hours in my form in my controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not binding your input values to your scope's properties.

Try [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel):

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
    New Chore: <br>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name"><br>
    Hours: <input type="text" name="hours" ng-model="hours"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: so does it even matter if there's a `name` attribute on my input if it's never being used?

Comment: @Edmund: the `name` property attribute on your input is to establish a control onto your formController: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state . It does not matter if it's never used.